# Binary search sort, Time out

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, timeout

## Climbing the Leaderboard. Terminated due to timeout :(

A HackerRank challenge of algorithm category.

---

My approach: To reduce the overhead when large arrays as input, I used map() and a Binar search function with it. No luck. I got 7/11 test cases passed. Can I ask for some help to improve my code. The code below is my solution so far. I need help to improve it.

[Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrZLe.png)

```
class Score_board:
    def climbingLeaderboard(self, scores, alice):
        self.boardScores = sorted(set(scores), reverse=True)
        alice_rank = list(map(self.rankBoard,alice))
        return alice_rank

    def rankBoard(self, current):
        score_bank = self.boardScores
        midIndex = len(score_bank)//2
        while midIndex > 0:
            if current in score_bank:
                return(self.boardScores.index(current)+1)
            elif current < score_bank[midIndex]:
                score_bank = score_bank[midIndex:]
                midIndex = len(score_bank)//2
            elif current > score_bank[midIndex]:
                score_bank = score_bank[:midIndex]
                midIndex = len(score_bank)//2
        else:
            boardIndex = self.boardScores.index(score_bank[0])
            if current in score_bank:
                return(self.boardScores.index(current)+1)
            elif current > score_bank[0] and boardIndex == 0:
                return(1)
            elif current < score_bank[0] and boardIndex == (len(self.boardScores)-1):
                return(boardIndex + 2)
            elif current > score_bank[0]:
                return(boardIndex)
            elif current < score_bank[0]:
                return(boardIndex + 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scores_count = int(input())
    scores = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    alice_count = int(input())
    alice = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    coord = Score_board()
    result = coord.climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice)
    print('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
    print('\n')
```

Comment: By Stack Overflow rules, the question should be self-contained, with all the information needed to diagnose the problem inside the post itself as much as possible. Supplementary links are okay, but your question should be fine without them. You haven't written what problem the code is trying to solve, or given an example of input data for which the program fails.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I will keep that in mind next time when I want to post a question. For this post, I have modified my question.